# SQL copy data from one column to another table specified column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have two tables name called by **`order`** and **`order_product`**, both tables have a column same name `model`, `order_product` `model` column have lots of data, but `order` `model` empty field.

i want copy `model` data from table `order_product` to `model` table `order`, how can i do this.?

i tried some SQL query, but the result not like really what i want, its look all field will be duplicate...

```
INSERT INTO `order` (model) SELECT (model) FROM `order_product`
```

Comment: i want just insert data from table order_product field model to table order field model...

Comment: when i tried above code the result look how many data field i have that will be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO order (model)
SELECT model FROM order_product
WHERE 'some field' = (some condition)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicate rows in the `SELECT` clause like so:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (model) 
SELECT DISTINCT model FROM `order_product`;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49d61/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

this should work for ur question?? kindly let me know what is the desired output u except such that i will update the answer

By seeing ur comments

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT distinct(col1)
FROM    table2
```

Comment: i tried your answer like ths  INSERT INTO `order` (model)SELECT distinct(model) FROM `order_product`  but still same above issue

Comment: like what can u show me some sample output thats d duplicates

Comment: my table have almost 20 fields, all field data duplicated but empty. only model field have data that we copied from other table

Comment: if u run this query u will just get the data of model from that table other fields will be empty or null only??? what do u want the fields where the data is empty

Comment: @mans do u want to update the column model or insert the column model?

Comment: i don't want nothing to do with my other fields, i need only replace my model field use that we copied data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19023/discussion-between-soul-and-mans)

Comment: @mans I think this answer is not correct, this is supposed to be `UPDATE` operation not insert since you only want to change the state of specific column. Insert will add new rows to your table and if you're using primary key you will get cannot insert `NULL` in yourTable.yourPrimaryKeyColumn please unAccept this answer and if you've found a solution please share it, regards